# Sailpoint rule to creat managedattribute

Tags: sailpoint

We are on SailPoint 8.3. I have created a rule to create a managed attribute and added the members. When I go to the Entitlement Catalog I see the managed attribute there but the members are missing. Also, the other entitlements have an Object tab but that’s missing too

Thanks

Created a rule. Expected all properties to be there